# How to remove stale computer accounts from SCCM automatically?

Tags: active-directory, sccm

I'm running SCCM 1702, and I've always wondered how I can automatically clean up the SCCM database of computers that have been decommissioned.

I've looked at the "Delete Aged Discovery Data" job in the site maintenance tasks, but I'm unclear exactly what it does.

**Here's what I want:**
We have an official PC decommissioning process and our Active Directory database is pretty clean.  When we remove a computer account from AD, I also want that account to be removed from the SCCM database within a reasonable amount of time (I'd prefer within 24 hours, but 7 days is also acceptable).

**Here's what I *don't* want:**
We have a lot of laptops that don't get seen by the network for sometimes months on end.  However, these machines are still active, still in AD, and should still be in the SCCM database.  I don't want those with an inactive status getting removed.

The documentation on this particular job in the Site Maintenance tasks is as clear as mud.  Computers that are in AD will still be picked up by system discovery, but they might not have a heartbeat for a long period of time.

Will this job accomplish what I want?  If not, is there another method to achieve this?